# Can someone tell me how to generate following xml using for xml in sql server

Tags: css, sql-server

```
<tr style="border 1px solid black">
    <th style="border 1px solid black">ID</td>
    <th style="border 1px solid black">NAME</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border 1px solid black">
    <td style="border 1px solid black">1</td>
    <td style="border 1px solid black">abc</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border 1px solid black">
    <td style="border 1px solid black">2</td>
    <td style="border 1px solid black"bcd</td>
</tr>
```

Please note that number of tr's depends upon number of entries in my table.
I want every td to be given inline css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FOR XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx):

```sql
SELECT   [@style] = 'border 1px solid black'
        ,NULL
        ,[td/@style] = 'border 1px solid black'
        ,[td] = 'Column1_Value'
        ,NULL
        ,[td/@style] = 'border 1px solid black'
        ,[td] = 'Column2_Value'
FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH ('tr')
```